# How to Save Document reference in firebase realtime data base

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

So I am using both firestore and Realtime database. I am trying to store a document in firestore and save that document reference into real time database.
here's my code:

```
firebaseFirestore.collection("Orders").add(postMap).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentReference>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentReference> task) {
                Map<String,Object> map=new HashMap<>();

                DocumentReference documentReference= task.getResult();
                firebaseDatabase.getReference(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).push().setValue(documentReference);
                firebaseDatabase.getReference(productBag.get(l).productModel.getUser_id()).push().setValue(documentReference);

            }
        });
```

this throws an error. I know we can't store document references in real time data base. Is there any way around?

Comment: "this throws an error" What error do you  get? Please edit your question to include the exact message and full stack trace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for [`DocumentReference.getPath()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentReference.html#getPath()), which will return a string of the path to the document. You can store this string in the Realtime Database, and later reproduce the `DocumentReference` from the string by calling [`FirebaseFirestore.document(...)`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/FirebaseFirestore.html#document(java.lang.String)).